# telnet a localhost

Tags: linux, telnet

Hi I am trying to understand network command like ssh and telnet. Unfortunately I dont have any other system besides my own so I am testing with localhost only. while i am able to do ssh locally when I am trying to do telnet locally I am getting this error

Command I am trying is telnet localhost, I am not entering any port no.

Trying 127.0.0.1...

telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused

Trying fe80::1...

telnet: connect to address fe80::1: Connection refused

telnet: Unable to connect to remote host

If I am able to do ssh locally, same should apply for telnet as well right?

Comment: Only if you have a server answering your connections on the port you are telneting to. If no port is provided, default is 23.

Comment: Depends. Is the telnetd daemon running on your machine?

Comment: I guess this question should belong to ServerFault

Comment: I don't think so. He's not running a server, just trying to understand how network services work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently you don't have telnet server running locally, at your machine.

To have a look how telnet command works, you could do next:

> telnet debra.dgbt.doc.ca
>
> telnet example.com 80

Comment: I am not able to access debra.dgbt.doc.ca, is it because no port has been mentioned?

Comment: Try something from this list: http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Public_server

Answer (score 1):

Install your Telnet server:

> Control Panels/Turn Windows Features On/Off --> Telnet server

For ssh you can install `freeSShd` that is a free ssh daemon